# Is it all right to educate users in general additionally to the answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette

Before answering a [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23478423/regex-in-textbox-instead-of-message-box), I started a little discussion to properly understand the OP's problem. Then I answered, and the answer was accepted, and everything is fine now.

One comment by the OP caught my attention, though:

> I don't get it, sorry.. I am really noob with vb

Is it all right to *educate* users a bit in general? I wanted to respond with:

> Don't use *slang* (like **noob**) - just say, that you are not experienced in VB.NET
>   or don't say it at all. It is not important that you are
>   not experienced, but that you are putting an effort (and you need to put more
>   effort before [asking a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Are such comments *tolerated* on SO (or even the SE network) or will they be viewed as displaying a *know-it-all* attitude? I know that personal remarks/comments can be easily (and quickly) misunderstood.

Comment: FYI, I use n00b all teh time, Y U have problem with Internet/1337/Meme speak?!?! Seriously though, it's such a small thing, why make a big deal out of it? I wouldn't consider it worth my time.

Comment: You're free to comment whatever you like unless it's not overly chatty, offensive, spam or otherwise disruptive. In this particular case though, I feel the comment is misdirected as you're mostly commenting on his use of the word "noob" which isn't really an issue you should concern yourself with - after all, he chose the word to describe himself, and like Cupcake says it's just internet lingo and not a big deal. I'd just have commented something along the lines of "keep on trying and you'll get it eventually"...

Comment: @Cupcake I agree, as I put in my answer, that this comment doesn't need a response. But I think the broader question here, "Is it all right to educate users a bit in general?", is worth addressing. It's good that people know that keeping the site clean is important.

Comment: For just this item, I'd probably not mention it at all. However if there is a lot of slang/txtspk in many of their questions, and you believe this is creating edit work, I'd add it as a comment under the question or under your answer. That then makes it easier to delete later on (once they have read it), and separates it from your answer where it is not relevant to all readers.

Comment: The problem with your specific example is that I don't see it as detracting from the quality of the site overall. If a user chooses to regard him- or herself as a "noob", that's their business and not something we need to be policing. Rather than "correct" the user, in this specific example, I would say something more encouraging. Perhaps something along the lines of, "That's okay. We all were at one time or another. You're putting forth effort and really trying to understand. That's what's important, and we all appreciate it."

Comment: I see one question in the title, and another in the body.  My answer to the title is unconditionally "Yes; it is OK to educate people about how to do things that are just outside the direct remit of the question".  Basic debugging techniques is one such -- they've got a problem and didn't know how to debug it; comments teaching a bit of debugging can help a lot.  For the question in the body, I probably wouldn't counter a 'n00b' comment, leaving it alone.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: That's what I interpreted from the title as well. I find it counterproductive to give someone their solution rather than explain why it's wrong, especially in cases where the issue is more a misinterpretation than an actual technical issue. Teach a man to fish, and so on.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Same here, but with a _hell yes_ example I see often on StackOverflow:  SQL injection, where the question/problem happens to be somewhere else and the bad query just happens to have been in the example

Comment: I'm not sure the title really fits what you are actually asking. Looking at the title I thought the discussion was going to be about whether it is right to provide more information than an OP originally asked, like for example extra tips etc. *(Just noticed in the previous comments this has already been pointed out).*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Are such comments tolerated on SO (or event the SE network)

IMHO, very much tolerated and expected from more experienced users. As long as you say it in a polite way then there shouldn't be any problem. I do it often and it was/is done for me. Most people respond kindly to it and thank you telling you that they didn't realize whatever it is you are communicating. The help topics cover a good bit of what users need to know but there are things that aren't spelled out so it's good to let them know.

> or will they be viewed as know-it-all attitude?

I have had people respond to me in this way also though much less so than those who accept and appreciate it. Again, as long as you try not to come off rude (sometimes is hard with differing cultures) then I think it is a good idea and shows that you want to keep the site clean and friendly.

**Additionally**, it also sometimes helps if you can explain, quickly and concisely, *why* they shouldn't be doing these things. Then you come across less as a "know-it-all" and more as an experienced user trying to teach a less experienced user the ropes.

However, I'm not sure *this* *particular* situation warrants any response to his comment. It is a bit of "noise" but not really hurting anything. But, do as you wish, just play nice.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot you ruined my answer ;)

Comment: I just edit it out just like I would "thank you", "regards" etc.

Comment: diz anwsoor iz su newb ;)

Answer (score 6):

As long as it is relevant to the question or the proper functioning of this site.

In your particular case:

> Don't use *slang* (like **noob**) - just say, that you are not experienced in VB.NET
>   or don't say it at all. It is not important that you are
>   not experienced, but that you are putting an effort (and you need to put more
>   effort before [asking a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

The usage of slang was not an impediment to communication; you understand what he meant (or you wouldn't have suggested an alternate wording), and therefore I'd consider the first part of your comment off-topic.

The second part was meant well, but quite generic (what was missing? The FAQ is long, and identifying the relevant section would make the feedback far easier to act upon). Instead, I'd probably have written something like:

> What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: Thanks for the good suggestions. I admit the example was probably not so well choosen, but you understood my *broader question* (as described by @codeMagic) correctly.

Answer (score 4):

N00bism is a state of mind, not an expression of unfamiliarity with a topic.
As such, education about a topic can't cure it.

But yes, teaching newcomers to a field general skills that can help them get along in that field is always a good thing. It might even help them ask more meaningful questions in the future (apparently this person was already on the right track if he both accepted an answer and didn't get downvoted into oblivion) :)

Some people will of course get angry at you for trying to teach them things, but you have to ask yourself if people who get angry at being educated about things that are outside the scope of their immediate problem (which scope is usually best, at least in their mind, served by giving them a cookie cutter solution they can just cut and paste into their code base or reports) are people who are worth educating.

Comment: `As such, education about a topic can't cure it`: sad but true \m/ :-)

Answer (score -5):

I usually come here to educate myself, not asking for direct solutions, but rather hints and/or keywords that show me a direction and help me find the solution for an actual problem myself.

Comment: This meta question is asking whether we should be educating users about *the use of Stack Overflow in general* when a problem is noticed, not whether people should be asking questions about programming in general.  That said, SO is designed to be a place where *specific* questions are asked, not broad, "explain that whole topic to me" questions.  They simply aren't wells suited to the design of the site.