# When a question is *almost* a good question

Tags: discussion, edits, upvotes

From time to time I see a question that is so close to being a good question. It has all the pieces, except things like:

- A clear language barrier (the user is unlikely to be a native English speaker) leading to grammar / spelling problems
- They write a legitimate [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but it has poor indentation
- Missing tags
- The automatic language detector doesn't work (for example, a question with both Java code and XML code), and it needs a `<!-- language: lang-xyz -->` tag

I am conflicted in these scenarios. I have a few options

1. Don't upvote the question

   - This makes me sad, because there's so much garbage on Stack Overflow these days that these near-winners should be rewarded
2. Upvote anyway

   - I do want the user to learn about the problems and not just think "oh what a great post!"
3. Edit, then upvote

   - This is what I most often do, but there still remains the problem of the user not really learning anything from this
4. Comment

   - It's probably more work for me to explain how to change the post than to just change it

I don't like any of my options, honestly. What do others think?

Comment: That is exactly what the edit button was designed for. Furthermore, if you want the user to learn something, you could leave a comment about what the problems in his post were. But editing is usually enough as it helps the user to see his mistakes (because they were what was edited)

Comment: Option 3 most definitely teaches the user how to improve their posts. You are leading by example. Combined with other questions posted where you didn't help improve the post, they'll quickly enough cotton on there is a difference in response.

Comment: The `<!-- language: lang-xyz -->` problem I get from time to time too and to be fair: I didn't know that solution. Maybe it would be good to add this as another field or as hint under the post for new users.

Comment: What answer do you *expect* on meta? The "good-citizen" way to deal with this is to edit the question. If you want to invest the time which is what all answers here assume.

Comment: @PeterMortensen haha "MVCE" rolls off the "tongue" so much better for me that I keep swapping the letters. Probably because of "MVC framework" :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The choice is pretty clear:

***Edit then up-vote***

The up-vote, of course, being up to you. There are times that you want to help someone, but ... don't feel that it's a question that we need to display as valuable. That's fine - it's your call.

If you want to *teach* as you're doing it, here's a trick:

- Edit, and leave a clear edit summary in the *plainest* English that you can muster to explain what you changed.
- Up-vote (if you wish, if you worked hard on it, it's probably worth one) and then leave a comment pointing at your revision, so the OP discovers it.

Something like this:

> I've made [link to revision]some edits to your question[/link] that I think better clarify the problem that you are having. Please review my edits to make sure that your question is still the same question you wanted to ask, and note the changes I made for asking in the future. Good luck!

.. or whatever you like, to that effect. Some changes we're considering in the current quality project ([meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/se-quality-project) | [meta SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/se-quality-project)) involve establishing a queue to help you help folks that could ask better questions over time, with a bit of help.

As long as you're actually *mentoring*, an action that *good* programmers take when they see actual potential - it's probably time well spent. Teaching programmers how to ask for help effectively is indeed mentoring, even if you're not helping them fix their problem directly by answering their question.

While we all see them large as life, revision histories (and edit summaries) aren't always discovered immediately, especially when the OP is in desperate need of an answer. Hopefully, we come up with a way to make this easier. We think we've got one but it still needs .. work.

Answer (score 45):

Edit! Then upvote if it is a good question just poorly constructed because they are new.

Sometimes I will leave a comment in the edit section saying something like,

> Please work on how you post questions. I have edited this time but you should pay attention to your formatting and tags (or whatever the current issue is)

That could be considered "noise" but it will help the OP to understand better how to post. As long as you put it politely, then I have noticed it usually gets a good response. For a more effective and elegant comment suggestion to leave, see [this answer by Tim Post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267473/when-a-question-is-almost-a-good-question/267512#267512)

I obviously don't follow those users around to see that they took my advice but they usually say thanks and that they will work on it in the future.

Remember to leave a good summary of the edit (as always) so they can understand what/why it was changed.

[Somewhat related to the commenting part of my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253656/is-it-all-right-to-educate-users-in-general-additionally-to-the-answer/253661#253661)

Comment: I like the edit + upvote **+ comment** idea. Maybe they won't listen but at least they'll read it.

Comment: Even if **they** don't listen, *someone* is likely to learn from it. And since SO isn't just about helping the OP, it's a success.

Comment: This is a good answer, I also left one because I had more to add than comments really serve. I'm glad to see voting on this go the way that it did :)

Answer (score 2):

Did the question accomplish what it's supposed to?

- Is the question an interesting/unique one?
- Did you understand it?
- Do you have all the information you need?

If so, then go ahead and upvote the question. If you're bothered by some flaws of the post, then you can edit them or you can let the OP know.

If you understood the post in the first place, you shouldn't worry yourself too much over minor formatting issues. You're primary goal should be to answer the question, not to judge it.

Stack Overflow isn't some sort of writing competition.

Comment: If so, leave it as is.  The flaws may actually be helpful, i.e., knowing that a person may be struggling with English may be a clue to the technical issue they are struggling with.  Maybe not, but in the history of computing, it has happened (e.g., Sys Hungarian vs. Apps Hungarian naming conventions).

Answer (score 2):

If it's poor English, punctuation, and/or indentation, and the poster is fairly obviously not an English-speaker or perhaps is simply unfamiliar with SO, then edit to fix the problems.  If, after editing, the question merits an upvote, then upvote.

If the problems are more obviously due to simple carelessness, and those problems make the question fall below the downvoting threshold, downvote.